# How do I force (subdomain) multisite to create new subsites with https?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Does anyone know how to force subdomain multisite to retain the URL schema (specifically https) when a new subsite is created?

By default, it creates subsites with the "siteurl" and "home" options urls with "http://".

There are a few lines in [ms-functions.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.4/src/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L1459) that explicitly tell subsite **NOT** to use the schema, so I'm wondering what the best way to change that is without modifying the source. Thanks!

Comment: like mentioned below you can modify .htaccess or you can modify the virtual host file in your servers config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the [Multisite Clone Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/), and I was able to write a function that hooks into the plugin during the cloning process, avoiding having to touch the core code.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'mucd_after_copy_data' ) ) {
function force_https($from_site_id, $to_site_id) {
        $site_url = get_site_url($to_site_id);
        $https_site_url = str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $site_url );
        update_blog_option( $to_site_id, 'siteurl', $https_site_url );
        update_blog_option( $to_site_id, 'home', $https_site_url );
    }
    add_action('mucd_after_copy_data', 'force_https', 10, 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical ways to do this are to either add something like the following to your install's `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or to use one of the "Force SSL" type plugins and Network Activate it.

Personally, I'm a fan of <kbd>[Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/)</kbd>.

If you're using a plugin like Domain Mapping, you can specify HTTPS in that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. We use mapping, and are able to force those domains to SSL, the problem we're facing is that the backend urls get used by wordpress even after the domain is mapped. This causes mixed content issues. 

I feel like there has to be a way to hook into when a new blog is created and force those to https.

Comment: Have you tried either the solutions I mentioned? The .htaccess will force any request to https, and the Really Simple SSL does the same - on both the front and admin side. There's really no need to hook into the new blog hooks, but if you insist, you'll need to hook a combination of  
[`switch_to_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog), `update_option('siteurl', ...)` and `update_option( 'home', ... )` to the [`wpmu_new_blog`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wpmu_new_blog) hook.

Comment: Yes, there are a couple reasons why I can't use an htaccess rewrite or one of those plugins. I did take a look through the Real Simple SSL plugin you mentioned, and they are just doing DB updates on those fields to get them to https. I think I might just write a cron job that does a similar action. Thanks again for your help and feedback, it's appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I am also looking to catch the site creation process and make the site https by default. Eg, when the email goes out to the user that they have created the site, the URL should be https... This is not about redirection, it's about creating a "default" for new sites.